# How can airflow worker get variables created in airflow web UI?

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

I create a variable in airflow web UI And try to get and echo it.

```
try:
    version=Variable.get("DayVersion")
except:
    version='Day'
start = BashOperator(
    task_id='start',
    bash_command="echo {}".format(version),
    dag=dag
)
```

In the server which run scheduler and webServer, the `$airflow test` command echo the value i created in web UI.

In the server which run worker, the `$airflow test` command echo default value('Day').

Answer (score 1):

The `bash_command` argument of `BashOperator` is a templated field, meaning Airflow will use Jinja2 to render the contents given an execution context, which Airflow handles for you.

Change your `bash_command` value to `echo {{ var.value.DayVersion or 'Day' }}`